# CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD before curl_easy_perform

Tags: php, c++, c, curl, libcurl

is it possible to get content length before doing curl_easy_perform, i need to know whats the total size of file at server before i download it 
any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I didn't get the solution there @Selçuk Cihan